# When is it true that $KM=K \cup M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $K,M$ are subfields of a field $L$, when is it true that $KM=K \cup M$?

I know that $KM$ is the subfield of $L$ generated by $K \cup M$, hence $L \cup M \subset KM$. But under which conditions we can have that $KM \subset L\cup M$?

Comment: Well, among other things a field must be have a structure of additive group. Try to prove that if $\;N,\,M\;$ are subgroups of a bigger group, then its union is a subgroup iff one of the subgroups contains the other one...

Comment: $K\cup M$ is not usually a field. Take $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$

Comment: Yeah, I know that the union of subfields is not always a field. But I'm searching under which conditions we can have that, @daruma

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. You're right
It can be solved using group theory